# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Tags: mysql, popsql

Trying to run this simple query, but getting this error
[https://prnt.sc/1rb6pl5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncILd.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OussZ.png  - Connection popup settings

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PopSQL: Try switching the Connection Type to local:
[image: Edit your connection].

Answer (score 0):

Make sure mysql is running on your server.